# How do I pass the value of this var via the parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http, express

In JQuery:

```
initSliders(socket, '!{request}');
```

`request` is an object (an HTTP request object in Express.js web app) that has such info as my `session`. When I pass this in to `initSliders()` it come in on the other side as the String literal "[object Object]". Why? I don't know. It behaves like an object before it passes in since commands like these execute:

```
console.log('!{request.session.user}');
console.log('!{request.session.date}');
console.log('!{request.session.city}');
```

Display things like

```
Alfred
11/13/2013
Manitoba
```

How can I keep it's structure when being passed into the function so I can reference it's properties like those above??

The `request` object is coming in through a render, via an app.js handler like this (which is why I use the single quotes and curly brackets around it, it's the only way I know how to reference this)

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard', {request: req});
}
```

Comment: Not sure I totally follow, maybe try initSliders(socket, JSON.stringify(request));

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried it. Inside the function request looks like this: "[object Object]". It's no longer an object with properties, it's just a String that says "[object Object]".

Answer (score 0):

It prints out `[object Object]` because `req.toString()` returns it. `res.render('dashboard', { request: JSON.stringify(req) })` also does not make much sense just because request is particularly huge object and you probably do not really want ALL the object properties being passed to render script. However, you can try... So it is highly recommended to pass only what is required as follows:

```
red.render('dashboard', { parameters : JSON.stringify({  param1 : req..., param2 : req.... and so on })
```